# What was the last (if any) Xcode shipped with iOS Simulator 3.0 and supporting iOS 4.2.1?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ipod-touch

I currently have an iPod Touch 2G model MC, running iOS 4.2.1 which cannot be downgraded AFAIK, but I need to build an iOS 3.0 app

So, it would help to have an Xcode with both an iOS 4.2.1 compatible SDK and iOS Simulator 3.0 too

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iPhone SDK 3.2 Final with Xcode 3.2.2](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.2__final/xcode_3.2.2_and_iphone_sdk_3.2_final.dmg) for Snow Leopard (10.6.0) has iOS Simulator 3.0 built-in

[Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 GM Seed](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.3_gm_seed/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3_gm_seed.dmg) for Snow Leopard (10.6.6) can be installed, then using the former DMG it could be installed iOS Simulator 3.0 with these packages:

"/Volumes/iPhone SDK/Packages/iPhoneSDK3_0.pkg"
"/Volumes/iPhone SDK/Packages/iPhoneSimulatorSDK3_0.pkg"